# missing arguments message in discord

Tags: discord.py

so i was making an help command with different help menu's. Like mee6 has. but i want to add an message for as there are no arguments given. How to do that? This is waht i have now:

```
@bot.command(name='help')
async def help(ctx, *, content):
    if content == ('Moderation'):
        await ctx.send(moderationmenu)
    if content == ('fun'):
        await ctx.send(funmenu)
    if content == None:
        await ctx.send('please provide an argument (Moderation / fun)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're able to provide default arg values like so:

```py
@bot.command(name="help")
async def help(ctx, *, content = None):
    if not content: # more pythonic way of checking a variable is None or not
        await ctx.send("Please provide an argument (moderation / fun)")
    elif content.lower() == "fun": # brackets not necessary
        await ctx.send(funmenu)
    elif content.lower() == "moderation": # makes it case insensitive
        await ctx.send(moderationmenu)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Sorry, I didn't recognise that category. Please choose (moderation / fun)")
```

A quick edit - if you have your menus sorted out into separate variables, you can map them in a dict:

```py
@bot.command(name="help")
async def help(ctx, *, content = None):
    menus = {"fun": funmenu, "moderation": moderationmenu}
    if not content:
        await ctx.send("Please provide an argument (moderation / fun)")
    else:
        try:
            await ctx.send(menus[content.lower()])
        except KeyError:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, I didn't recognise that category. Please choose (moderation / fun)")
```

---

**References:**

- [Default args](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/)

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you also wouldn't mind [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you, as it could help others find the solution if they're facing the same issue. Happy coding, good luck with the bot :^)

Comment: Oh yes sure, Thanks(-: